Is one SynchronisationContext used over multiple threads/tasks?
Is there a situation where a SynchronisationContext is used over multiple threads/tasks in Blazor?
I want to determine whether a method has an components BuildRenderTree in its call stack. To do so i created a custom ComponentBase where i wrap the BuildRenderTree with custom code. My approach would be to check the SynchronisationContext. As i understood it is uniquely for one component, and therefor the execution of BuildRenderTree will not be "interrupted" by other threads/tasks with the same SynchronisationContext set. Did i get this right? Are there any pitfalls with using the SynchronisationContext for this case? (i am not sure if the components used in the razor file are rendered within the BuildRenderTree but i would handle this case correctly alreay)


As i understood it is uniquely for one component,

Not really. It is attached to the SignalR circuit and shared by the whole UI. It is null when running on WebAssembly.

and therefor the execution of BuildRenderTree will not be "interrupted" by other threads/tasks with the same SynchronisationContext set.

BuildRenderTree()  is not async, it won't be interrupted by other Tasks. It might be pre-empted by other threads but that should not affect what's on the call stack.

But is there any chance that the other thread has the same SynchronisationContext?

As WebAssembly is single threaded, the BuildRenderTree shouldn't be pre-empted by any other threads at all (as there are none) , is this right?

The gist here is that the synccontext is neither required nor suitable for what you want.

What would be more suitable then? Just the current thread?

It's not clear that you would need anything.

What do you mean? How could i determine whether a method has an components BuildRenderTree in its call stack than?

I wasn't sure how you would do it with a context. Better explain why you think you need this, there probably exists a better solution.

As i said i need to check if a method is in the stack trace - i try to build something similar to angular signals, therefore i need to track all values that are accessed within the BuildRenderTree to trigger the rerendering properly.
I just use the render context as an dictionary key to get the corresponding custom ComponentBase/BuildRenderTree
